# What method can give me coordinates for a pointer touch?

Tags: java, android

I need to get touch coordinates on the screen outside my app. I see android apps like Hiromacro being able to record touch events. What method can I call to give me a MotionEvent for every pointer touch?

Comment: This sounds very broad, please look at the [help/on-topic]. What is your specific issue?

Comment: I need to get touch coordinates on the screen outside my app. I see android apps like Hiromacro  being able to record touch events. What method can I call to give me a MotionEvent for every pointer touch?

Comment: Now that's a specific on-topic question. I suggest you [edit] your post with this information, so as to make your question less broad.